# What does bis_skin_checked="1" mean? It's showing on most of my elements when using chromes code source view?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm confused I don't know if the latest update of chrome AKA version 73 just integrated this attribute on purpose but I'm getting a strange attribute that I did not added into my web pages and i'm wondering what this means in chrome?

**CHROME BROWSER**

[image]

**EDGE BROWSER**

[image]

Should I be concern with this? It's only showing on Chrome.

Comment: It's probably added by an extension you've installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the SpeakIt! [Version 0.3.20] extension installed for Chrome [Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)] on Windows 10, and I am seeing the same  bis_skin_checked="1" when it's enabled.  When I disable the SpeakIt! extension, the bis_skin_checked="1" goes away.

Comment: Wow are you spying on me? Ha ha ha who are you? Just joking. xp Wow I have that installed as well and I did what you did and I got the same result. Ooo... wow thank you very much for your response. I wonder why it does that and what is the purpose for SpeakIt in doing that as of right now i'm not worried any more because its not causing any problems for me so far so i'm good now thanks.

Comment: I get this attribute on all `div` elements, but I do not have that extension.

Comment: Not only this Extension. It also happened to my VPN extension. I noticed the same when the extension enabled.

Answer (score 21):

There is another Chrome and Firefox plugin that does same, sadly, but probably one of best VPN tools [Urban VPN Browser Extension](https://www.urban-vpn.com/free-products/free-browser-extension/). The solution is same, just deactivate. Btw, those guys have other extensions, haven't tested others.

Comment: Truly annoying. Thanks for posting this, saved me from debugging.

Comment: "one of the best VPN tools" -- they use the same free proxies that all free VPNs use: same servers, same IPs, same locations.

Comment: @undefined It is a Peer-to-Peer VPN, with no bandwidth caps or device limits, 80+ server locations, what else to expect from a totally free service?

Comment: @skobaljic I'm just saying they use the same services a lot of other VPNs do. I went on a spree detecting different VPN proxies by ISP ASN (autonomous system number, e.g. ISP id) and found out all free VPN extensions for chrome use the exact same servers. Now, UrbanVPN has one of the greatest collection of these publicly available proxies, but I'd argue it's the best free forever VPN.

Comment: I have that extension installed. the class names go away if the extension is removed

Answer (score 5):

Just uninstall any type of VPN that you installed in you browser and afterwards `bis_skin_checked`="1" will removed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute is added just because of one of an extension of the Chrome Browser you have installed in your Chrome Browser. I also got this attribute added to my HTML when checking in the console. Then I replicate this by deactivating extensions one by one and found it's adding from **Hover Over** extension.

Answer (score 0):

This thing append from different Chrome/Mozilla extension.

Disable recent extensions to see the changes(**bis_skin_checked="1" goes away**
).

Answer (score 0):

This problem has happened to me recently. I installed the Urban VPN plugin and after that, I faced this issue. But uninstalling the plugin, the problem is solved.